# Linq two-step Func to one line lambda

Tags: c#, linq

I've created a `Func<int[], decimal>` that sums all the elements in an array of ints:

```
Func<int[], decimal> testFunc1 = delegate(int[] intArr)
{
    int[] filter = intArr.Where(i => i > 0).ToArray();
    decimal r = intArr.Where(i => filter.Contains(i)).Sum();
    return r;
};
```

How can I condense this down to something that can be consumed by

```
Enumerable.Sum(TSource, Func<TSource, Decimal>)
```

I've tried this, but I'm getting an intellisense error from the lambda expression that says I can't convert type `bool` to type `decimal`:

```
decimal result2 = testInt.Sum(i => i > 0);
```

Comment: btw, what is the use of `int[] tempResult = intArr.Where(i => filter.Contains(i)).ToArray();` this statement.

Comment: sorry, it should not be included. i'll remove, it is obscuring the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement inside sum does not select which elements in the collection to sum, it selects which field on the object to sum. What you actually want is:

```
decimal result2 = testInt.Where(i => i > 0).Sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple Linq extension methods along the way:

```
decimal r = intArr.Where(i => i > 0).Sum();
```

This sums all the results that are filtered by the Where function.

Answer (score 0):

```
testInt.Where(i => i > 0).Sum()
```

If you really insist on a lambda you can pass to Sum directly then

```
testInt.Sum(i => i > 0 ? i : 0)
```